# Python console not launching properly from command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command

I seem to have problem launching python from command line. I tried various things with no success.
Problem: When trying to run `python` from the command line, there is no response i.e. I do not get message about 'command not found' and console does not launch. Only option to open python console is to run `C:\Python34\python.exe` directly. Running using `python` command does not work even when in the python directory but `python.exe` launches. Issue with the launching this way is that python console is launched in new window. This whole problem is present only on one machine while on my other machine I am able to run python correctly and console launches in the command prompt window from which the `python` command was executed.

PATH is correctly set to 
`C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;...`
and `where python` correctly returns `C:\Python34\python.exe`. I verified that running other commands imported through PATH (such as `javac`) run correctly.

Things I tried:

- Completely re-installing python both with x86 and x64 python installations with no success.
- Copy installation from my second machine and manually set the path variables - again no success.

Can anyone hint how to resolve this behavior?

(Additional info: Win 8.1 x64, python 3.4.2)

Comment: Did you try setting the path to `C:\Python34` ? Notice the lack of the last backslash.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Interesting idea, but does not fix it. Notice that `where python` already finds correct path to the executable. My most logical theory is that python.exe actually launches when invoked with `python` command but immediately terminates without printing any error or other messages. When I try running pip using `pip` command from any location, it runs but in new window just like python when invoked using `C:\Python34\python.exe` command. Does python maybe have a log file somewhere?

Comment: The `C:\Python34` works for my on Windows 7. Have you tried both 32-bit and 64-bit Pythons to see if there's a difference?

Comment: "Things I tried: Completely re-installing python both with x86 and x64 python installations with no success." as I state. Don't get me wrong, I have same setup on other machine (Win 8.1 x64, Python 3.4.2) where the `python` command launches the python console properly.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Since no feasible solution was found in 2 days, I decided to wipe all keys containing 'python' from registry as well as some files that were not parts of other programs. This resolved the issue after re-installing python.

If anyone finds the true cause of this misbehavior and other - less brutal - solution, please write it here for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Recent Python installer has option to add PATH.
If you didn't use it, you can register directory where python.exe is to PATH environment variable.

But I prefer `py` launcher. It may be installed via Python 3.3 or 3.4.
With it, you can start Python via `py` or `py -3.4`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: In my question I mentioned that PATHs are set correctly. `py` command indeed launches python shell but also as new window and not  in the windows command line as on my other machine. I might not have explained myself properly in my question but I am looking for a way to fix discrepancy between behaviors on the two machines, not work-arounds.

Comment: Do you use normal cmd.exe?

Comment: Yes, attempted both with and without administrator rights.